# Getting top 1 record for each project

Tags: ms-access

```
Project- ID,Name
ProjectProgress - ID,ProjectID,ProgressID, Date
```

I need to get the Top 1 record for each Project, however i keep hitting a brick wall, does anyone have an idea how i can achieve this, I am trying to return

```
ProjectName, ProgressID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't describe how to determine which record is the TOP 1.  Is it the most recent date for each ProjectID?

If so, tell us what more you need after starting with this:

```
SELECT ProjectID, Max([Date]) AS MaxOfDate
FROM ProjectProgress
GROUP BY ProjectID;
```